# Phonegap-iOS Prevent Documents folder backup on iCloud

Tags: ios, cordova

I've an App that has been rejected because of an improper use of the iCloud backup.

Shortly, I have a pre-populated DB stored in the Documents folder and i need to exclude it from iCloud backup.

My questions are:

1) Does the BackupWebStorage setting in the config.xml set to "none" do the work? Or it just prevents the WebKit folder to be backed up?

2) If its doesn't work, i know i should use the following code:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

But (blushing), I don't know how i should specify the file in this code, let's say the path is:

Documents/0000000000000001.db

Where have I to indicate it?

Really, every kind of help will be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Ale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try what I told you on the phonegap's google group?

You can use the setMetadata function on the .db file, something like this

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("0000000000000001.db", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {

        // Set the metadata
        fileEntry.setMetadata(success, fail, { "com.apple.MobileBackup": 1});

    }

    function success() {
        console.log("The metadata was successfully set.");
    }

    function fail() {
        alert("There was an error in setting the metadata");
    }
```

Comment: Bingo! It worked, it file is flagged:      
`iMac-xxxxxxxx:Documents xxxxxxxx$ xattr -l 0000000000000001.db
com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem: com.apple.MobileBackup`
 -  
Just a doubt: is com.apple.MobileBackup still valid or is it deprecated?
 - 
The objective-c way is something I'll keep working on. Unfortunately I'm in a hurry and need to kick it on AppStore

Comment: When you set the file metadata with the com.apple.MobileBackup, it internally do the same as the objective-c way proposed by Lee Crossley, it's not deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I believe that setting is only for the web storage (although this isn't clear).

In the past I've made absolutely sure that nothing has been backed up to iCloud in the Document or Library directories using this gist I wrote last year:

https://gist.github.com/leecrossley/4130115

Comment: Great! just a couple of questions: have I to put it in appDelegate.m?

Comment: Yes, that's where I did it

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to add the following code:

```
NSString* doc = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* lib = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if (version < 5.1)
{
    NSLog(@"************ iOS 5.0");
    u_int8_t b = 1;
    setxattr([doc fileSystemRepresentation], "com.apple.MobileBackup", &b, 1, 0, 0);
    setxattr([lib fileSystemRepresentation], "com.apple.MobileBackup", &b, 1, 0, 0);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"************ iOS 5.1");
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:doc];
    [url setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: Nil];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:lib];
    [url setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: Nil];
}


NSLog(@"************ FILES FLAGGED");
```

Right after

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
```

in AppDelegate.m

It runs smoothly but, when I test the result using the Terminal:

- opening the Documents folder of the Simulator App in a new Terminal window
- Checking the file attributes (My DB path is Documents/0000000000000001.db):

  ```
  xattr -l 0000000000000001.db
  ```

And I get no response, which (at least I think) means the file hasn't been flagged.

Is there something I've missed?

Thanks for your patience

Alessandro

Comment: The code you tried set nobackup flag for Documents and for Library folders. And this will prevent iCloud backup for all files in them.
I checked attributes after using this code:
`xattr -l Documents`
`com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem: com.apple.MobileBackup`